# Retrieving images from the path data saved at SQL database

Tags: php

Part of my code to retrieve the stores images and the content from the SQL database (only the path is saved at the database) is as follows. I get the content displayed except the images.

My database record says the path as; `C:/xampp/htdocs/bro/productLoader/uploaded_files/1377935517-IMG_0150.JPG`

The image source I entered does not seems to be helping me. How do I adjust my approach to make sure the pictures are extracted from the database?

code as follows;

```
<?php
$j=0;
while ($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
?>
    <tr style="height:100px; font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;">
    <td style=" width:100px;">        
    <img src='<?php $rows['pictures'];?>'><br><br>
    </td>
    <td style="text-align:justify;"><?php echo $rows['description'];?><br><br></td>
    <td style="text-align:right;"><?php echo $rows['brand'];?><br><br></td>
    <td style="text-align:right;"><?php echo $rows['model'];?><br><br></td>
    <td style="text-align:right;"><?php echo $rows['unitprice'];?><br><br></td>
    <td style="text-align:right;"><?php echo $rows['availability'];?> units available<br><br></td>
    <td><input type='submit' id='buynow[]' class='buynow' name='but' value='Buy'><br><br></td>
    </tr>
<?php
$j++;
}
echo "</table>";
}?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to insert only relative path excluding your document root. That is if your document root is set till htdocs folder only (which is default in apache for localhost) then you have to insert image path from this document root in your case

/bro/productLoader/uploaded_files/1377935517-IMG_0150.JPG

And yes you need to echo that variable too.

Answer (score 2):

Try html link first

```
<img src='bro/productLoader/uploaded_files/1377935517-IMG_0150.JPG' />
```

Ok

Try this fixed:`<img src='<?php echo substr_replace($rows['pictures'], '',0, 16);?>'/>`

Comment: Your way it works. But the path stored in the database is as above. How to I tackle?

Comment: If you can't change the way it stored in database or use [substr_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php) replaces a copy of string delimited by the start and (optionally) length parameters with the string given inreplacement.

Comment: In this case [substr()](http://php.net/substr) would be simpler: `substr($path, 16)`